# Array buffer allocation failed

Tags: vue.js, three.js

I´m constantly getting this error message during webpack build
And the console print shows no way to trace the origin in vscode
I´m using webpack with vue.js

Error image:

[image]

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: try to build  feeding `--max-old-space-size` a larger number like `2048` or `4096`

Comment: @Eldar. I´m use Vue js. Having trouble to set this using Vue

Comment: It's a node option where you can use like `node --max_old_space_size=4096` and then you can keep using your `vue cli`. Related [thread](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-cli-javascript-heap-out-of-memory/48185/7)